# ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY)

Tags: sql, window-functions

I am using the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY....) AS RK` command and this is my output:

```
+--------+-------+------+------------+----+
| SCHOOL | MONTH | YEAR | DATE       | RK |
+--------+-------+------+------------+----+
| STAN   | 05    | 19   | 2019-05-01 | 1  |
+--------+-------+------+------------+----+
| UCSC   | 05    | 19   | 2019-05-01 | 2  |
+--------+-------+------+------------+----+
| BERK   | 05    | 18   | 2018-05-01 | 3  |
+--------+-------+------+------------+----+
```

I do a `SELECT * FROM (result from the query above) WHERE RK = 1` and it should return:

```
STAN    05  19  2019-05-01  1
```

however, it returns:

```
UCSC    05  19  2019-05-01  2
```

I'm not sure why though as the SQL Command logic is correct.

Comment: Add a tag identifying the RDBMS you are using, the query text.

Comment: What is the actual query?

Comment: `(PARTITION BY what)` ? plus: `ORDER BY ...` Things to remember: in SQL, without `order by` **there is no order**

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with the information given???

Comment: @wildplasser This cannot be a question of ordering can it? Fields ```(SCHOOL, MONTH, YEAR, DATE)``` might change, sure. But ```RK``` should always be one, as it is part of the condition right?

Comment: How many total rows are you getting? Your use `partition by` would suggest you expect more than one. I suspect that you're getting the first row as desired and also the second one which you don't want at all.

Comment: From the example shown above, it appears that RK values could have been generated with (order by (select null)). Since there is no ordering RK values can be unpredictable.

Comment: You are right that if the table you give is indeed the result of your nested PARTITION BY subselect, and you SELECT from that with the WHERE clause you state, you should be getting the row you state.  SQL engines are very very unlikely to make mistakes against such basic stuff.  So the most likely scenario is you made some mistake in your SQL no matter how convinced you are you made none.  People here can only tell if you ***give the SQL***.